# How to log in mysql DB in remote host

Tags: mysql

I use mysql in vm1 host which ip is:10.104.xx.xx. 
I can log in DB successfully like is:

```
mysql  -uStack -pqwerasdf##123 hpcusers;
```

and the grants of Stack user is:

```
show grants for Stack@'%';
```

the result:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for Stack@%                                           |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'xiezy'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `hpcusers`.* TO 'xiezy'@'%'          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now I want to log in DB from remote vm2 host. I use:

```
mysql -h10.104.xx.xx -uStack -pqwerasdf##123 hpcusers
```

But it is unlucky, I am fail, the result is:

```
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.104.xx.xx' (110)
```

The mysql version in vm1 host is

```
Server version: 5.6.25-73.1 Percona Server (GPL), Release 73.1, Revision 07b797f
```

The mysql version in vm2 host is:

```
Server version: 5.7.24-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

At the same time, I can

```
ping 10.104.xx.xx
```

successfully in vm2 host. and I can log in vm1 successfully

```
ssh root@10.104.xx.xx
```

Who can help me? Why I can't remote log in DB ?

Comment: This is a network problem, as explained in the linked duplicate. Most likely, port 3306 is not open.

Comment: yes, I edit iptables file, it is ok now, thank you